# Dropzone - is it possible to move the upload progress bar?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, spring-mvc, dropzone.js

I am using `Dropzone` with `jQuery` and `Thymeleaf` in my `Spring MVC` application.

With minimal configuration, the `Dropzone` works brilliantly, with one small cosmetic issue. I am setting `autoProcessQueue` to false, so that the queue is not processed until a submit button is clicked. This means that the progress bar, which shows 0 progress until the Submit button is clicked, obscures the filenames in the preview. This can been seen in the attached image. The three filenames are just about visible behind the progress bars, but they are very dim.

[image: dropzone with filenames obscured]

My Dropzone configuration is pasted below: -

```
Dropzone.options.frmTarget = {
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        paramName: 'file',
        clickable: true,
        maxFilesize: 20,
        uploadMultiple: false,
        parallelUploads: 10,
        maxFiles: 20,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        acceptedFiles: '.png,.jpg,.pdf,.doc,.docx,.xls, .xlsx,.xml,.bmp,.msg,.txt',
        dictDefaultMessage: 'Drag files or click here to select',
        init: function () {
            var myDropzone = this;
            myDropzone.removeAllFiles();

            myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
              myDropzone.removeFile(file);
            });

            myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function (file) {
              $("#dropzone-info").show().delay(3500).fadeOut();
            });

            $("#button").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                myDropzone.processQueue();
            });

            $("#button1").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
            });
    }
}
```

This is how the `Dropzone` is added to the HTML pages, where it is combined with other elements in a form with use of `Thymeleaf` to bind model data to the form: -

```
<form id="frmTarget"
      th:object="${metadataListWrapper}"
      class="dropzone"
      th:action="@{/content/upload/{app}(app=${metadataListWrapper.applicationName})}"
      method="post">
    <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(metadataListWrapper.metadataDefinitionList)}"
         th:each="metadataHolder, iStat : ${metadataListWrapper.metadataDefinitionList}">
        <div th:if="${metadataHolder.includeInIngestionForm == true}">
            <input th:field="*{metadataDefinitionList[__${iStat.index}__].value}" type="hidden"/>
            <span th:replace="fragments/non-value-hidden-fields :: non-value-hidden-fields"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input th:field="*{applicationName}" type="hidden"/>
    <input th:field="*{applicationDisplayName}" type="hidden"/>
</form>
```

I would be very grateful for any suggestions and ideas to get round this. For example, would it be possible to shift the progress bar down so that it appears below the filename instead of on top of it, or to not display the progress bar at all before upload is initiated? Or perhaps the opacity of the progress bar could be reduced to 50%? Many thanks.

EDIT:

I just wanted to include a screenshot below of the Dropzone having implemented Vince's excellent suggestion in the accepted answer. In my case, the CSS change alone sorted the issue out. Compare this to the screenshot from my original post. The progress bar now appears under the 'Remove file' link and does not obscure the filename - exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks again @Vince Polston - great work!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell the easiest way to move the dropzone progress bar and/or change the opacity would be adjusting the CSS.

**Working Codepen**: https://codepen.io/vpolston/pen/JjvMLpr

**Walkthrough video on YouTube**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3w6PvLRRgY

If we silo down to `.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-progress` we can adjust the properties of the progress bar itself. For my testing I changed both the position as well as the background rgba.

CSS

```
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-progress {
  top: 115% !important;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,90%) !important;
}
```

JS

```
Dropzone.options.myGreatDropzone = { 
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  paramName: "file", 
  maxFilesize: 2, 
  accept: function(file, done) {
    if (file.name == "justinbieber.jpg") {
      done("Naha, you don't.");
    }
    else { done(); }
  }
};
```

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.3/dropzone.css" integrity="sha512-7uSoC3grlnRktCWoO4LjHMjotq8gf9XDFQerPuaph+cqR7JC9XKGdvN+UwZMC14aAaBDItdRj3DcSDs4kMWUgg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.3/dropzone.js" integrity="sha512-9e9rr82F9BPzG81+6UrwWLFj8ZLf59jnuIA/tIf8dEGoQVu7l5qvr02G/BiAabsFOYrIUTMslVN+iDYuszftVQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-great-dropzone"></form>
```

**I think that will get you where you want to be? If so please mark the answer.. answered! If you have another question I'd be glad to try to tackle it at my earliest convenience.**

Thanks,
VP

Comment: This is great, thank you. I really appreciate such effort and detailed advice :)

Comment: You are very welcome Jon! :)